# Symfony - skip check with method for specific entity object

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, entity, symfony4

I have a issue that I am trying to figure out for few days now.

I have wrote an overlapping method which check if the dates I entered overlap with data existing in a database. The method works for all objects.

What I want to accomplish is to skip the entity with the specific ID I found with first function and check every other row in database except the entity with that ID.

Does anyone has an idea how can I accomplish that?

```
public function editEntity(
    int $id,
    DateTime $startDate,
    DateTime $endDate,
    string $name,
): MyEntity {

    /** @var MyEntity $entityObject */
    $entityObject = $this->entityManager->getRepository(MyEntity::class)->find($id);

    if (empty($entityObject)) {
        throw new Exception('Entity not found.');
    }

    if ($this->overlap(
        $entityObject->getId(),
        $startDate->format("Y-m-d"),
        $endDate->format("Y-m-d")
    )) {
        throw new Exception('Dates ovelap!');
    }

    $entityObject->setStartDate($startDate);
    $entityObject->setEndDate($endDate);
    $entityObject->setName($name);

    $this->entityManager->persist($entityObject);
    $this->entityManager->flush();

    return $entityObject;
}
```

I want to skip the check for ID that is found by doctrine ***->find()*** method.

Comment: I'm not absolutely sure that I understand question correctly. `overlap` method do some checks over some data, and you would like to exclude from this data `$entityObject` by `$entityObject->getId`. If it's true, then please provide `overlap` method implementation, because skip should be done inside it. Without method it hard to help youю

Comment: Sounds like a simple `AND id != {value here}` addition to the query.

Answer (score 0):

As I understood you would like to persist an Entity with the dates are not already occupied from another record in the database. Is that correct?

If yes then just change the overlap method to query /you will need a custom query in the repository/ to count the records matching the dates and excluding the ID of the current Entity. If the result is > 0 just throw the exception or whatever you want to do.